# How should I install Splunk from remote tgz package?

Tags: ansible, splunk

Im trying to perform an additional task on the output of `stdout_lines`.

Here is the playbook:

```yaml
- name: Change to Splunk user
  hosts:
  sudo: yes
  sudo_user: splunk
  gather_facts: true
  tasks:
    - name: Run WGET & install SPLUNK
      command: wget -O splunk-9.0.2-17e00c557dc1-Linux-x86_64.tgz https://download.splunk.com/products/splunk/releases/9.0.2/linux/splunk-9.0.2-17e00c557dc1-Linux-x86_64.tgz

    - name: run 'ls' to get SPLUNK_PACKAGE_NAME
      shell: 'ls -l'
      register: command_output

    - debug:
        var: command_output.stdout_lines
```

I am using `wget` to download Splunk on the server and I need the Splunk package name so that I can extract the file in the next task.

For that, I tried to register `ls -l` as `command_output`.
Now, I need to untag it (`tar xvzf splunk_package_name.tgz -C/opt`), but I dont know how I can use the `stdout_lines` output in my tar command.

Comment: Ansible rule of thumb: it is not because you know how to do something in the command line that you should do the same in `shell` or `command`. Use the dedicated modules of Ansible.

Answer (score 3):

In Ansible, your use case should resume to one single task, using the [`unarchive`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/unarchive_module.html) module, along with the `remote_src` parameter set to `true` and the `src` one to your URL.

As described in [the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/unarchive_module.html#parameter-src):

> If `remote_src=yes` and `src` contains `://`, the remote machine will download the file from the URL first.

So, you end up with this single task:

```yaml
- name: Install Splunk from remote archive
  unarchive:
    src: "https://download.splunk.com/products/splunk/releases/9.0.2\
          /linux/splunk-9.0.2-17e00c557dc1-Linux-x86_64.tgz"
    remote_src: true
    ## with this, you will end up with Splunk installed in /opt/splunk
    dest: /opt
```